# Calling a MATLAB function from C#

Tags: c#, matlab, com, matlab-deployment, dde

I developed a MATLAB function, and I'm looking for a way to call that function from another C# application and pass some parameters to it and get the results in the C# program.

I heard that I can use [Dynamic Data Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) (DDE) or COM objects, but have can I do it?

Comment: Did you try reading about PInvoke attribute in C# documentation? It will give you an idea of calling COM objects from .NET World.

Comment: You can pass matlab function handles to C# delegates. See my similiar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408624/passing-matlab-methods-as-delegates-to-net-object

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is nice example in the [MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987).

It shows three ways on how to communicate with [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB):

1. COM
2. MATLAB .NET Bulider
3. MATLAB compiler

**COM** (I do not have any experience with it)

Cons: MATLAB is required to be installed on the target computer.

**MATLAB .NET builder** compiles your MATLAB code to the .NET assembly and you can use it directly.

Pros: MATLAB is not required to be installed on the target computer

Cons: It's expensive

**MATLAB compiler** compiles your MATLAB code into a C/C++ library or EXE file. You can use it through [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

Pros: MATLAB is not required to be installed on the target computer

Cons: It's expensive, a lot of P/Invoke.

Comment: you should point out that for the second and third options, the produced binaries require the [MCR](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) to be installed on the target machine (MCR is freely available)

Comment: The link is now dead :-(

Comment: `MATLAB .NET builder` is expensive with respect to what ?

Answer (score 6):

There is a third option: [delegates](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsu3p4r-1.html). Starting MATLAB -> load .NET assembly -> execute .NET  function with delegate handle to a MATLAB function.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great example [on this site](http://www.codingterminal.com/articles/082015/2/Integrate%20Matlab%20with%20C%20sharp.php)  on setting up everything. You can use MATLAB .NET deployment tool.

You need to

- Install MCR (Matlab Compiler Runtime).
- Deploy your Matlab function to .NET Assembly using Matlab Deploy
  Tool. This will create a .dll file.
- Add .dll reference inside your .NET project.
- Add reference to MATLAB.NET.

The advantage of this method is that the target machine does not require MATLAB to be installed, but on the downside the execution is quite expensive.