# How to call matlab function from VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, matlab, mixed-programming

I need in my program to load an image data like what matlab does when it loads images and store it in a matrix, and then I will do some operations on this matrix and view it after that.
so I need some help, how can i use matlab functions with loading images and displaying them from visual studio 2010

Thanks a lot

Comment: Matlab version is (Matlab 7.9.0 R2009b)

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901664/call-matlab-function-from-c-sharp? Does this help?

Comment: I've seen it, but I can't download the tools described for free, or maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: Maybe, you should rather use `openCV`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer I posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474835/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-visual-studio-mfc-project/20739873#20739873), there are two ways to call Matlab inside visual-studio:

1. Distribute MATLAB into independent shared library: check out my [blog-post](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2012/04/matlabc-cmatlab.html) on how to do this (with detail steps and example).
2. Call MATLAB Engine directly: Refer to [another blog](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2013/12/matlabc-mixed-programming-call-matlab.html) of mine for more info.

Answer (score 0):

i tink this link is useful
http://internetexception.com/post/2013/01/20/Using-with-Matlab-from-C-sharp-application.aspx

```
write this code inside any c# function

        var activationContext = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("matlab.application.single");
               var matlab =(MLApp.MLApp)Activator.CreateInstance(activationContext);
            matlab.Execute("cd 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB';");
            matlab.PutWorkspaceData("y", "base", simArray);
then any code you used in matlab can written in 
matlab.Execute("");
```