# How to call Matlab functions from Visual studio mfc project?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, mfc, mixed-programming

What I have done is following the guidline in this
[website](http://michael-stengel.com/blog/?p=89)

Now, I want to use some functions like `rgb2gray()` and `imresize()`... but I dont know how to use them, or I dont know which header file should I include in my project?

I have tried other way by creating a C++ shared-library in Matlab, then used it in VS 2012, but I could not add the DLL file to my project when I added new references. it is like that: [image]

Please help me!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- If you really want to call Matlab inside visual-studio, there are two ways:

  1. Distribute MATLAB into independent shared library: check out my [blog-post](http://blog-ythu.github.io/2012/04/29/mixed-programming-distribute-MATLAB/) on how to do this (with detail steps and example).
  2. Call MATLAB Engine directly: Refer to [another blog](http://blog-ythu.github.io/2013/12/27/mixed-programming-call-MATLAB-directly/) of mine for more info.
- On the other hand, it seems that you don't need to call Matlab to achieve your goal. `OpenCV` library will offer functions similar to `rgb2gray()` and `imresize()`.

Comment: I'd go with the openCV option.

Comment: @Shai Nice step to go. :)