# Xna framework and matlab

Tags: windows, visual-studio, matlab, xna

I am developing a game which would be reading real time data from Matlab. The game is being developed for Windows OS and not XBox or WIndows Phone. Is there any way , I can interface matlab with XNA. ALso can I use the usual Visual Studio 2008/2010 for developing the game rather than using Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNA is used with either C# or Visual Basic so it would, on it's own, have no way to interface with MathLab.  We need to know what language you are using to better help you.

Most likely you are looking for C#.

Such interfaces are beyond me; however, to get you started there is this Question/Answer which has a link to MathLabCentral for C#:
[Calling a MATLAB function from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901664/calling-a-matlab-function-from-c-sharp)

**For the second part of question**:
If by "usual" Visual Studio you mean the paid version then the 2010 version will work. 
Again, without knowing which version of XNA you plan on using there could be multiple possible answers.  XNA 3.1 and older will work with 2008.

You can also use Visual C# 2010 Express if C# is your target language.  Don't know.

[XNA friendly IDE's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/10/01/10070558.aspx)