# Matlab exprnd(a,b,c) analogue for C#?

Tags: c#, matlab

How to get the number in C# from the same distribution as a function exprnd() in Matlab ?

Comment: you can call matlab function from c# 
read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901664/calling-a-matlab-function-from-c-sharp or here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
static readonly Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

public static double ExpRnd(double mu)
{
    return -Math.Log(randomNumberGenerator.NextDouble()) * mu;
}
```

If you want the `m`×`n` matrix, use

```
public static double[,] ExpRnd(double mu, int m, int n)
{
    var arr = new double[m, n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            arr[i, j] = ExpRnd(mu);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Note: The `System.Random` class is *not* thread-safe. If you have more than one thread calling `ExpRnd` above, you must be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post might help you:

http://ericlippert.com/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data/

If you know -- or can work out -- the *quantile function* of the distribution you want then you can transform the (roughly) uniform distribution you already have into the given distribution.

As I describe in my blog post, the quantile function is the inverse of the cumulative distribution, and the cumulative distribution is the area under the distribution. Since the distribution you want is e<sup>-x</sup> it should be easy to work out the integral and the inverse.

Comment: That's also how my answer works. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates) gives the quantile function as $F^{-1}(p)=-\ln (1-p)\mu$ and notes that the "one minus" part can be left out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some external signal processing library like [meta.numerics](http://www.meta-numerics.net/Documentation/index.html)

Under `Meta.Numerics.Statistics.Distributions` namespace, have a look at `ExponentialDistribution` class and the corresponding `GetRandomValue(Random)` method.